# waitKey(0) not working opencv c++ on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, image-processing

I have a problem with the waitKey(0) command using opencv c++ on macOS.
In short, by pressing enter or any other key, the program does not end.

The program (I'll put the simple code below) does run correctly and shows me the grayscale image, but the only way to make the image disappear is by clicking control c.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(argv[1]); 
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv:cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::namedWindow("Example 1"); 
    cv::imshow("Example 1", gray); 
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0; 
}
```

I also tried to run waitKey(5000) and it correctly waits 5 seconds before ending.
Any ideas?

******* EDIT *****

I found out the problem... and it was not really a problem, I was just stupid. Indeed on macOS you have to click on the image and after that you can put the input key and terminate the program correctly. Hope this help any other dummy engineer like me who encounters this "problem".

Comment: You need to make sure that the window is in the foreground. It does not put itself in the foreground automatically on macOS I’ve noticed. Try clicking on it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I found out the problem, and it was not really a problem... I was just dummy. As you said indeed, you have to click on the image in order to get the command working. After that, pressing any key makes the program go on and terminate correctly. Don't know why on macOS it is like that, cause on ubuntu I didn't get this silly problem. Anyway thanks a lot!